# Filter response from api and show them in different div on the basis of points

Tags: javascript

I want to sort them on the basis of points. I suppose the points id less than 100 then it should be appended to a `<div class="small">` div and if it is higher then 100 and it should be appended to another div.

[image: points based sort]

Right now the whole data is showing in the same div. How do I filter them so can be shown in different div according to the points they have.

[image]

Code

```
function getLeaderbordDetail()
{
    var html_data= '';
    myMemberId = NextBee.NBUtil.getSession(advertiserId + '_memberId');
    var selector = {
        'leaderBoardCont': $('#leaderBoard-cont')
    },
            noDataHtml = '<center><span class="no-leader">No Data Found!</span></center>',
            getRowFn = function (srNo, point, firstName, lastName, schoolName) {

                var htm = '';
                var schoolLogo = '';




                if (schoolName == null || schoolName == "")
                {
                    var schoolLogo = '<div style="background: url(https:...../img/avatar.png)" class="profile-pic-circle" />';
                }
                else
                {
                    var schoolLogo = getLogoPath(schoolName);
                }


                 htm +=     '<div class="lb-user">'
                 htm +=     '<div class="row">'
                 htm +=         '<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">'
                 htm +=             '<div class="lb-nummber"><span>' + srNo + '</span> ' + schoolLogo + '</div>'
                 htm +=         '</div>'
                 htm +=         '<div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">'
                 htm +=             '<div class="lb-desc">'
                 htm +=                 '<h4>' + firstName + '</h4>'
                 htm +=                 '<p>' + point + ' Points</p>'
                 htm +=             '</div>'
                 htm +=         '</div>'
                 htm +=     '</div>'
                 htm +=     '</div>'
                 return htm;

            };

    var currentTime = new Date();
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
    var firstDay = year + "-" + "01" + "-" + "01";
    var lastDay = year + "-" + "12" + "-" + "31";
    api.getRealTimLeaderBoardByType({
        'member_program_id': programId,
        'limit': 10,
        'type': 'points',
    'startDate':firstDay,
    'endDate':lastDay
    }, function (res1) {
        var htm = '', leaderBoardData, leaderBoarddataCnt = 0, srNo;
        if (typeof res1.status !== 'undefined') {
            switch (res1.status) {
                case 'success':
                    leaderBoardData = res1.response.leader_board;

                    for (var idx in leaderBoardData) {
                        srNo = leaderBoarddataCnt + 1;
                        if (leaderBoardData[idx]['memberInfo']['first_name'] == null)
                            leaderBoardData[idx]['memberInfo']['first_name'] = "--";

                        if (leaderBoardData[idx]['memberInfo']['last_name'] == null)
                            leaderBoardData[idx]['memberInfo']['last_name'] = "--";
                        if($.inArray(leaderBoardData[idx].member_id,['4482435','4483316','4482441'])==-1){
                            htm += getRowFn(srNo, leaderBoardData[idx]['point_count'], leaderBoardData[idx]['memberInfo']['first_name'], leaderBoardData[idx]['memberInfo']['last_name'], leaderBoardData[idx]['memberInfo']['profile_phto_url']);
                            leaderBoarddataCnt++;


                        }

                        if (leaderBoardData[idx]['member_id'] == myMemberId) {
                            myMemberId = "";
                        }

                    }


                    break;
                default:
                    htm = noDataHtml;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            htm = noDataHtml;

        }
    selector.leaderBoardCont.html(htm);

                    var lbd_length = leaderBoardData.length 
                    console.log(lbd_length);
                    if(lbd_length < 10 ) {
                             html_data +=   '<div class="lb-user">'
                             html_data +=   '<div class="row">'
                             html_data +=       '<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">'
                             html_data +=           '<div class="">BECOME A <span class="bold">DVD CREW</span> TO SEE YOUR NAME HERE!</div>'
                             html_data +=       '</div>'
                             html_data +=   '</div>'
                             html_data +=   '</div>'

                        $("#leaderBoard-cont").append(html_data);
                        // var virtualdiv_length = 10 - lbd_length;



                    }


    });

}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: like `leader_board.forEach(function(key, eachItem){if(eachItem[index]<100) $('#small_div').append(smallhtml) else $('#large_div').append(largehtml);})`?

Comment: yes exactly like that..